# If values in column are less than ten characters, add a 0 to the start

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add logic to one of my stored procedures to update an entire column on a table. If the value in the column is less than ten characters long, prepend a 0 to the start.

E.g. if the value is 123456789, update the field to be 0123456789. However, if the value is 1234567890, ignore this record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMNNAME ='0'+COLUMNNAME
WHERE LEN(COLUMNNAME) < 10

Comment: But this will only work as you want if the length is 9

Comment: @ankyskywalker I never stated that all of the fields are required to have a length of ten. Only that if they did not have a length of ten, that the 0 was prepended. Worked it out in the end.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is:

- concatenate a static 10 character length text composed of only 0 values.
- use the RIGHT() function to substract only the last 10 characters of your new string, which should contain the original "non-zero" characters, and the additional "0" characters, up to the 10 character limit.

The code would look like:

```
create table #temp (val varchar(30), val_new varchar(10));

insert into #temp (val) values (1234567890), (123456), (123)

update #temp
set val_new = right('0000000000' + val, 10)

select * from #temp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
declare @t table (num varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('123456789')
insert into @t values ('1234567890')

Update @t set num =case when len(num) < 10 then '0'+ num
else num end

select * from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a built-in function to do this, `format()`:

You can be explicit about the format:

```
select format(123456789, '0000000000')
```

Or construct it:

```
select format(123456789, replicate('0', 10))
```

Before this function was available, the trick was to use right and prepend the value.  You could express this as:

```
select right(concat(replicate('0', 10), 123456789), 10)
```

The use of `concat()` is preferable to `+` because it works as expected for numbers -- which is presumably what you are starting with.

Answer (score 0):

declare @t table (num varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('12345678')
insert into @t values ('1234')
insert into @t values ('123456')
insert into @t values ('1234567890')

Update @t set num =case when len(num) < 10 then REPLICATE('0',10-len(num))+ num
else num end

select * from @t

Answer (score -1):

If its SQL Server ther are multiple solutions to this

1:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + '123456789', 10);
```

2:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + '123456789', 10);
```

3:

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR('1234567', 10),' ','0');
```

https://database.guide/left-padding-in-sql-server-3-lpad-equivalents/